# Dirichlet prime counting function?

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ be coprime (i.e. $a \perp b$). Let $f(a,b,x)$ denotes the number of the primes such that $p=ak+b$ and not greater than $x$. For example $f(4,1,10)= 1$.

Is there an asymptotic formula for $f(a,b,x)$ which is similar to prime number theorem?

Comment: Yes, it's usually called (not surprisingly) the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions#Distribution

Answer (score 0):

There are $\sim\frac{x}{\varphi(a)\log x}$ primes of the form $ak+b$ below x, a consequence of the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions (as Greg mentioned).